# How to modify an XML file in-place with XmlStarlet when there is xmlns attributes

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to modify the following XML file in-place;

```xml
<widget id="" android-version="" ios-version="" version="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
...
</widget>
```

Particularly trying to modify the values of `id` `android-version` `ios-version` and `version` attributes.

I'm using the following CMD to modify the empty string value of `id` for example passing a value to it from the command line with `$1`;

```bash
xmlstarlet edit --inplace \
--update "//widget/@id" \
--value $1 config.xml
```

This is working fine when I remove the 4 xmlns attributes. I tried to specify these as namespaces with `-N` but still couldn't modify. I want to be able to modify the values mentioned above without removing xmlns attributes.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I was making a mistake when specifying the namespace. Using the following format works;

```bash
xmlstarlet edit --inplace -N a="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" \
--update "//a:widget/@id" \
--value $1 config.xml
```

Note: I'm using `--inplace` to modify the file in-place without appending.